# Test failed with error in fastlane

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, fastlane

when test is run through fastlane it fails with no such module `Alamofire`. please advice

```
> Compiling Constants.swift

[x] /Users/stevejobs/Documents/Development/Project-G/ProjectG/Repository/UserRepository.swift:10:8: no such module 'Alamofire'

import Alamofire
   ^


> Compiling RegisterViewController.swift

[x] /Users/stevejobs/Documents/Development/Project-G/Project-G/Repository/UserRepository.swift:10:8: no such module 'Alamofire'

import Alamofire
   ^


2018-07-18 12:38:02.160 xcodebuild[3528:114637] Error     Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=14 "Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9r/4z5xs53d3b55jnddyc8bm1g40000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-DCC3811A-224F-4AA7-9575-906F2900372E/Project-GTests-0A12DD23-88A5-429A-BE87-5DF131B0B53A/Session-Project-GTests-2018-07-18_123759-jw3pTl.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9r/4z5xs53d3b55jnddyc8bm1g40000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-DCC3811A-224F-4AA7-9575-906F2900372E/Project-GTests-0A12DD23-88A5-429A-BE87-5DF131B0B53A/Session-Project-GTests-2018-07-18_123759-jw3pTl.log}
2018-07-18 12:38:02.160 xcodebuild[3528:114637] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=14 "Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9r/4z5xs53d3b55jnddyc8bm1g40000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-DCC3811A-224F-4AA7-9575-906F2900372E/Project-GUITests-0D9C98C0-8BBA-4E97-88D9-157AB4DBDCFD/Session-Project-GUITests-2018-07-18_123759-tAdazU.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9r/4z5xs53d3b55jnddyc8bm1g40000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-DCC3811A-224F-4AA7-9575-906F2900372E/Project-GUITests-0D9C98C0-8BBA-4E97-88D9-157AB4DBDCFD/Session-Project-GUITests-2018-07-18_123759-tAdazU.log}

Testing failed:
No such module 'Alamofire'
** TEST FAILED **
```

pod file

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Project-G' do
 # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'KVNProgress'

# Pods for Project G

target 'Project-GTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'KVNProgress'
# Pods for testing
end

target 'Project-GUITests' do
inherit! :search_paths
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'KVNProgress'
# Pods for testing
 end

end


and I don't install pod through fastlane
```

My FastFile

```
class Fastfile: LaneFile {
 func customLane() {
    let itcTeamId = "39941823"
    let username = "iosapp@dreamapps.com"
    let appIdentifier = "com.softence.Project-G"
    let appleId = "iosapp@dreamapps.com"
    let devPortalTeamId = "5PN99X4SDS"
    let scheme = "Project-G"
    let xcodeproj = "Project-G.xcodeproj"

    let versionNumber = getVersionNumber(xcodeproj: xcodeproj)

    cocoapods(
        clean: true,
        repoUpdate: true,
        podfile: "./Podfile",
        tryRepoUpdateOnError: true

    )

    latestTestflightBuildNumber(
        appIdentifier: appIdentifier,
        username: username,
        version: versionNumber,
        teamId: itcTeamId
    )

    let fastlaneContext = laneContext()

    let currentBuildNumber = fastlaneContext["LATEST_TESTFLIGHT_BUILD_NUMBER"] as! Int

    // Incremeting build number
    let newBuildNumber: Int = currentBuildNumber + 1

    incrementBuildNumber(
        buildNumber: String(newBuildNumber),
        xcodeproj: xcodeproj
    )

    buildIosApp(scheme: scheme)

    uploadToTestflight(
        username: username,
        appIdentifier: appIdentifier,
        appleId: appleId,
        teamId: itcTeamId,
        devPortalTeamId: devPortalTeamId
    )
}
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to give you an answer. Do you actually use Alamofire? how are you including it into the project, do you use pods? does your fastlane configuration install the pods, does it run pod repo update before it does, what does your podfile look like, what steps to you have etc etc etc

Comment: @Scriptable I have updated the question please check

Answer (score 1):

You should add cocoapods action to your Fastfile.
Check documentation https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/cocoapods/.

Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem "cocoapods"
gem "fastlane"
```

And to your Fastfile:

```
default_platform(:ios)

$XCODEPROJ = 'your_proj_name.xcodeproj'
$TARGET = 'your_target_name'
$SCHEME = 'your_scheme_name'

platform :ios do
    desc 'Builds and archives the project'
    lane :build_only do
    cocoapods(
        clean: true,
        podfile: "./Podfile",
        try_repo_update_on_error: true
    )
    gym
  end
end
```

Comment: where should I include that in Fastfile. can u please explain that

Comment: @Mohanraj added description

Comment: [15:35:33]: You passed invalid parameters to 'cocoapods'.
[15:35:33]: Check out the error below and available options by running `fastlane action cocoapods`
+----------------+-----+
|     Lane Context     |
+----------------+-----+
| VERSION_NUMBER | 1.0 |
+----------------+-----+
[15:35:33]: Unresolved conflict between options: 'repo_update' and 'try_repo_update_on_error'

Comment: I had updated the question with my fast file please check

Comment: @Mohanraj you can use only one of these options. I've updated answer. In case you need update repo every time, use 'repo_update' in case of error, use  'try_repo_update_on_error'.

Comment: Even after trying to set tryRepoUpdateOnError, it returns the same error  [!] Unresolved conflict between options: 'repo_update' and 'try_repo_update_on_error'

Comment: @Mohanraj just remove one of these options.